# Neglecting script tag contents using DOM Xpath

Tags: php, xpath

Im using `xpath` to retrieve contents from an article. Unfortunately, within my xpath query it sometimes contains javascript.

Here is my current xpath query:

`$xpath = '//div[@class="post"]//p';`

Now, how do i remove anything that is within a `<script>` tag?

Comment: I assume you would also like to eliminate the `<script>` tags themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath will not filter child data yet return the parent.  It is a selector language.  You could return all children of p tags that are not script tags; however, your hierarchy would be lost.

Your best solution is to get the results from the xpath query you have an manipulate the query results to remove elements that are script tags.